# Ordering results in rails 3..It works like magic, but why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

```
class Course < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :course_category
  belongs_to :client
  belongs_to :user_created, :foreign_key => :user_created_by, :class_name => "User"
  belongs_to :user_updated, :foreign_key => :user_last_updated_by, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :course_steps, :dependent => :destroy
  has_many :steps, :through => :course_steps
  has_many :course_requests
end
```

Here is output from the rails console...

```
>> c=Course.first
=> #<Course id: 1, course_category_id: 1, client_id: 1, user_created_by: 1, user_last_updated_by: 1, title: "Test Course 1", summary: "", hidden: false, auto_register: false, created_at: "2011-03-08 01:03:47", updated_at: "2011-03-08 01:03:47">
>> c.course_steps
=> [#<CourseStep id: 3, step_id: 2, course_id: 1, position: nil, created_at: "2011-03-08 15:03:44", updated_at: "2011-03-08 15:03:44">, #<CourseStep id: 4, step_id: 3, course_id: 1, position: nil, created_at: "2011-03-08 15:03:46", updated_at: "2011-03-08 15:03:46">]
>> c.course_steps.order("id DESC")
=> [#<CourseStep id: 4, step_id: 3, course_id: 1, position: nil, created_at: "2011-03-08 15:03:46", updated_at: "2011-03-08 15:03:46">, #<CourseStep id: 3, step_id: 2, course_id: 1, position: nil, created_at: "2011-03-08 15:03:44", updated_at: "2011-03-08 15:03:44">]
>> c.course_steps.order("id DESC").to_sql
=> "SELECT \"course_steps\".* FROM \"course_steps\" WHERE (\"course_steps\".course_id = 1) ORDER BY id DESC"
>> c.course_steps.order("position DESC").to_sql
=> "SELECT \"course_steps\".* FROM \"course_steps\" WHERE (\"course_steps\".course_id = 1) ORDER BY position DESC"
>> c.steps.order("position DESC").to_sql
=> "SELECT \"steps\".* FROM \"steps\" INNER JOIN \"course_steps\" ON \"steps\".id = \"course_steps\".step_id WHERE ((\"course_steps\".course_id = 1)) ORDER BY position DESC"
>> c.steps.class
    => Array
    >> c.course_steps.class
    => Array
    >>
```

The parts that I am confused by are: (I am glad they work, but I am just wondering why)

1. The fact that I can call "order" on course_steps (which is an array) c.course_steps.order("id DESC")!?!?
2. The fact that I can call c.steps.order("position DESC") when position is not even part of the steps table. It somehow does a magical join.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The fact that I can call "order" on
>   course_steps (which is an array)
>   c.course_steps.order("id DESC")!?!?

As I see it, rails doesn't immediately query a database after each of the chained methods. Instead, it processes the whole chain and constructs the query.
So `order` is not called on the `course_steps` array. It just appends an `order` part of the query.

Here's a qoute from the Beginning Rails:

> Notice that when you call the order
>   method, it returns an array object as
>   you may have expected.  One thing that
>   happens on the background is that
>   Active Record allows you to chain
>   calls to multiple  methods before
>   sending the command to the database;
>   so you can call all, followed by
>   order, and some  other methods we’ll
>   talk about in the next chapter, to
>   create more precise database queries.
>   Also, Active  Record is smart enough
>   to use lazy loading, a practice that
>   only hits the database when
>   necessary—in  this example, when you
>   call the each method.